# Low pass filter for accelerometer

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, accelerometer, lowpass-filter

I'm creating an app for windows phone using c# that uses the accelerator but its not smooth when displayed on the screen. I only need to move the Y-axis. I have seen this formula on microsofts website but I'm not sure how i should use it

```
O = O-1 + α(I – O-1)
```

where O is the output, α is the coefficient and I is the input(raw value)

how do i implement this into my code which is

```
private void UpdateUI(AccelerometerReading accelerometerReading)
{
    statusTextBlock.Text = "getting data";
    Vector3 acceleration = accelerometerReading.Acceleration;
    // Show the numeric values on screen.
    yTextBlock.Text = "Y: " + acceleration.Y.ToString("0.00");

    //low pass filter
    //????

    //move ball on screen
    var TopMar = (278.5*acceleration.Y)+278.5;
    var BotMar = 557 - TopMar;
    yDot.Margin = new Thickness(203, BotMar, 203, TopMar);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your title. Please see, "Should questions include tags in their titles?", where the consensus is "no, they should not". http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 0):

If Vector3 has overloaded the operators, this should do:

```
private Vector3 MeanAcceleration = null;
private void UpdateUI(AccelerometerReading accelerometerReading)
{
    const double alpha = 0.05;

    statusTextBlock.Text = "getting data";
    Vector3 acceleration = accelerometerReading.Acceleration;
    // Show the numeric values on screen.
    yTextBlock.Text = "Y: " + acceleration.Y.ToString("0.00");

    //low pass filter
    if (MeanAcceleration == null)
        MeanAcceleration = acceleration;
    else
        MeanAcceleration = (1 - alpha) * MeanAcceleration + alpha * acceleration;

    //move ball on screen
    var TopMar = (278.5 * MeanAcceleration.Y) + 278.5;
    var BotMar = 557 - TopMar;
    yDot.Margin = new Thickness(203, BotMar, 203, TopMar);
}
```

You need a field (or something of similar scope) and assign it the mean value. Every timestep, you update this mean value.

Alpha must be between 0 and, 1, to effectively low-pass the signal it should be 0.1 or below. Decrease this if the output is too wiggly and increase alpha if the output is too slow. If both is the case, you probably need a more sophisticated digital filter.

If the beginning is not important, you can initialize the mean with something like

private Vector3 MeanAcceleration = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

but I'm not sure about the constructor, because I don't know exactly which Vector3 that is.